# What is the difference between global definitions section and components section?

Tags: swagger-2.0, openapi

What is the difference between the global `definitions` section and the `components` section in Swagger 2.0?

I came across a Swagger definition YAML file which is marked as `swagger: '2.0'`.
It has one section called `definitions` just below `parameters`. This is similar to what is described in
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/basic-structure/
under the "Input and Output Models" section.

Also further down the file, it has the `components` section with the `schemas` section underneath it. That is similar to what is described in
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/components/
This looks like OAS3.

However, this specific YAML file has both sections. I am not exactly sure whether `definitions` is for Swagger 2.0 and `components` and `schemas` is in OAS 3.0. Is that so?

Can both `definitions` and `components` be used in the same YAML file of type `swagger: '2.0'` or should we stick to either `definitions` or `components`?

```yaml
# definitions section looks like this
definitions:
  User:
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
      name:
        type: string
    # Both properties are required
    required:  
      - id
      - name
# components section looks like this
components:
  schemas:
    Address:
      type: object
      properties:
        line1:
          type: string
        city:
          type: string
```

Answer (score 15):

> I am not exactly sure whether `definitions` is for Swagger 2.0 and `components` and `schemas` is in OAS 3.0. Is that so?

Yes, exactly.

The `definitions` section is used in OpenAPI 2.0 files (`swagger: '2.0'`).

The `components` section is used in OpenAPI 3.x (`openapi: 3.x.x`).

> Can both `definitions` and `components` be used in the same YAML file of type `swagger: '2.0'` or should we stick to either `definitions` or `components`?

No, you can't mix 2.0 and 3.x syntax in the same file. If your file is `swagger: '2.0'` you must use 2.0 syntax. If it's `openapi: 3.0.0` you must use 3.0 syntax.